# What is this fallback character called?

Tags: fonts, character

When some certain characters cannot be displayed usually you get a: ⍰ (U+2370). Oftentimes on iOS I get these guys though:

> [image]

What's this name of this six-lined fallback character?

Comment: How can you tell that this is a character icon and not a graphical icon like an SVG or raster PNG?

Comment: @ChristosLytras I can't. It does replace undisplayable Chinese characters though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shapecatcher](https://shapecatcher.com/) to draw and identify symbols. (And you don't even need to be good at drawing!)

The only six line characters that it found for me, are "Musical symbol six-line staff"  (0x1D11B), and "Hexagram for the creative heaven" ䷀ (0x4DC0).

Whether one of those characters is the one used on iOS, I cannot tell. Either would be a strange choice for a replacement character.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it to be the "hexagram for the creative heaven" symbol as I've seen this before replace Chinese characters on apple developed OS's. Just out of interest what symbol were you trying to type or were you just curios to what this symbol was?

Comment: 'HEXAGRAM FOR THE CREATIVE HEAVEN' (U+4DC0). Anything from cjk ext.s seems to revert to this.